# How do I preserve the transparent background when converting an SVG file to PNG with MiniMagick in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I am trying to automatically convert SVG images to PNG with Minimagick. I have a Rails application where I need to automatically convert uploaded SVG files. The app runs on Heroku. These SVGs typically have a transparent background.

This is the code I am using:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :email do
    process :convert_to_png
    def full_filename (for_file = model.logo.file) 
      "#{model.friendly_id}-#{model.id}-logo-email.png"
    end 
  end 

  def convert_to_png
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.format 'png'
      img = img.density 300
      img = img.resize '800x400'
      img = img.background 'none'
    end
  end

end
```

This creates a png image with width 800. However the property `background 'none'` is not applied. The original image has a transparent background, and the resulting converted image has a white background instead.

I have seen that Minimagick calls the mogrify command of Imagemagick, and I have found the command I have to call to create the image I need, but I have trouble converting it into a function for the uploader. Using the same parameters in the same sequence for the uploader doesn't work because it throws an error if the line `img = img.format 'png'` isn't called first.

```
mogrify -density 300 -background none -resize 400x200 -format png myfile.svg
```

Comment: You try background like this: `img = img.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"` ?

Comment: Try your background before the resize

Comment: Thank you! I have tried both of these options but the converted background is still white instead of transparent.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I don't use this library so all of this is gleaned from the docs and the source code. If these don't work for you I will remove the post it was just too long for a comment

Here are  few suggestions:

Maybe try [`combine_options`](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#combine-options) instead? *"`MiniMagick::Image#combine_options` takes multiple options and from them builds one single command."* which is more in line with your desired CLI call

```
def convert_to_png
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.combine_options do |i|
      i.density 300
      i.background 'none'
      i.resize '800x400'
      i.format 'png'
    end 
  end
end
```

Another option is to touch the [*Metal*](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#metal) and generate that exact command.

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Mogrify.new do |mogrify|
  mogrify << "input.svg"
  mogrify.density(300)
  mogrify.background('none')
  mogrify.resize('800x400')
  mogrify.format('png')
  mogrify << "output.png"
end
#=> `mogrify input.svg -density 300 -background none -resize 800x400 -format png output.png`
```